# application start from command shortcut

Tags: terminal, keyboard, applications, command-line, shortcut

Hi I'm using grandma3 and for more options like soundcodes I'm required to start from the command line. which can become quite furstrating after a while. I'd wish it could be done in a press of a button that runs the script in the command line, like in windows when you can take the app from it's origin and make a shortcut to desktop
the line of script is has follows:

/Applications/grandMA3.app/Contents/MacOS/gma3_1.6.3/app_gma3

any help would be nice
thanks in advance

Comment: It's tough to know exactly what you're trying to do without being familiar with the software. I'm not sure how many lighting techs we have here. Have you asked MA about this?

Comment: You can write a "shell script" and make it executable with `chmod` then you get an executable file that you can run by double click and run. If you are trying to start the program, the command is `open -a Safari` where the flag `-a` indicates an App is what you are opening, and in place of Safari you would write the name of your App to be opened.

Comment: Please add a specific example of how you call/start the application from the command line, including parameters.